# extending the notion of missing values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have third party data which has some goofy convention for missing values (in my particular application, they use '-'). Is there some elegant way to tell pandas to extend its notion of missing value?

Comment: df.replace('-',np.nan) ?

Comment: yeah, just use replace.  you can also specify `na_values` while reading a csv to add more strings to the default defn of na

Comment: @JohnE Cool, that is the sort of thing I had in mind, but I am using pd.read_html()...

Comment: did you try `na_values` with read_html?  it looks like you can based on the documentation and a lot of the read_csv options work with other reads even when it isn't documented

Comment: @JohnE No, I did not see it, but certainly will try - that seems like the "morally pure" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be by replacing '-' with np.nan.

```
df.replace('-', np.nan)
```